# Add Custom button Pdftron viewer

Tags: pdftron

How to add custom option in pdftron AdvancedViewer's Three dots menu or Kebab Menu

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow menu can be customized using the custom toolbar configuration

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/xamarin/guides/getting-started/using-fragment/#customize-the-options-toolbar

https://www.pdftron.com/api/xamarinandroid/tools/api/pdftron.PDF.Config.ViewerBuilder2.html#usingcustomtoolbar

Comment: mDocumentView.ToolbarPrepareOptionsMenu += FileView_ToolbarPrepareOptionsMenu;
mDocumentView.ToolbarOptionsItemSelected += MPdfViewCtrlTabHostFragment_ToolbarOptionsItemSelected;

Comment: private void FileView_ToolbarPrepareOptionsMenu(object sender, PdfViewCtrlTabHostBaseFragment.ToolbarPrepareOptionsMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            var saveMenuItem = e.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_save);
            if (saveMenuItem == null)
            {
                e.Menu.Add(Resource.Id.action_save, Resource.Id.action_save, 0, Resource.String.menuname);
            }
        }

Comment: private void MPdfViewCtrlTabHostFragment_ToolbarOptionsItemSelected(object sender, PdfViewCtrlTabHostBaseFragment.ToolbarOptionsItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            if(e.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.action_save)
            {
                //Handle Option Selected here
            }
        }